# Javascript Custom Callback Function

Tags: javascript, callback

I have one concern about javascript callback function. What I understood is callback function should allow other statements to proceed if it takes time. So I have created one custom callback function to check but I'm not getting expected result. Am I doing wrong anything here?

```js
function test(param1,param2,cb){
  if(typeof(cb) === 'function') return cb(param1,param2)
  else console.log('im not a func');
}

function calbackFunc(a,b){
    console.log('Hi i am '+a+' '+b);  
}
setTimeout(function timeout(){
        console.log('timeout')
},0);

test('callback','function',calbackFunc);

console.log('console');
```

## Output

"Hi I am callback function"

"console"

"timeout"

As per the callback function, 'console' should come first. but it's not happening. Like setTimeout is working fine. Then why my custom callback function behaving like setTimeout.

Comment: You're logging `console` after running your callback function.

Comment: A "callback" is just a regular function passed as a parameter. So it is synchronous like other functions.

Comment: The callback you are passing runs before `test()` finishes executing. Calling `setTimeout` with a delay of 0 will not run the passed function immediately, it's still getting scheduled. It will just run very very soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronous behavior and callbacks in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847917/asynchronous-behavior-and-callbacks-in-javascript)

Comment: Then how can i make asynchronous callback function without using SetTimeout

Comment: The functions will execute when their turn arrives in the script, synchronously except for those which are schedule not to return the result immediately e.g. `setTimeout()`, `setInterval()` and function returning a deferred object like XHR 
 (Ajax) call.

Comment: @user3790136 What is your expected output? "console" > "Hi i am callback function" > "timeout" ??

Comment: @Rohit416, Yes but I don't want to move up console physical. It should print asynchronously like this "console" > "Hi i am callback function" > "timeout"

Comment: [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), it would be a nice read. You may or not use it now but it will be helpful.

Comment: @Liton "*How can i make asynchronous callback function without using SetTimeout*" - you can't. That's how asynchrony works. https://stackoverflow.com/q/22286887/1048572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting confused between the *Stack* and the *Queue*.

### The Event Loop

In [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), synchronous calls are going into the *stack* while asynchronous calls are going into the *Heap*, and when done are back in the *Queue*. A function is moving from the *Queue* to the *Stack* only when it's empty.

[image]

### In your example

#### phase 1: call `setTimeout()`

this puts the function in the *heap*, and since the timeout is set to 0, it right away moves to the _queue. does it means that it's executing right away? no, because that your current function (the "main") hasn't finished yet.

#### phase 2: call `test()`

this code is *synchronous*! when calling `test` we add a function to the *stack*. then we add the `cb()` call to the *stack*.
that means that we need to finish all both before we can proceed to phase 3.

#### phase 3: `console.log`

nothing to explain here

#### post phase 3

the current "main *stack* is finished, so the function from the *queue* is now added ti the *stack*, logging `'timeout'`.

Comment: Thank you. Really helped me to understand how it internally works.