# Unable to access address from geocoder - reverse geocoding

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

The following is my javascript function in angular

```
getLocationName(latitude, longitude){
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
   var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();
   geocoder.geocode({ 'location': latlng }, (results, status) => {
     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[1]) {
           return results[1].formatted_address;  //prints value here but not outside the geocoder function
        }
     }
});
 }

location_name = this.getLocationName(lat, lng);
```

I'm getting location_name as undefined. May I know how to access the address.

[image]

Comment: Can you attach the results(response) ?

Comment: @Zelda7 I've attached

Answer (score 0):

`geocoder.geocode` takes a callback function, executes async, and then calls the callback when it has the results.

This means `getLocationName` returns before the callback has been called, and since there's no return statement it returns `undefined`.

`return results[1].formatted_address;` returns `formatted_address` from the callback and NOT from `getLocationName`!

```
(results, status) => {
 if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    if (results[1]) {
       return results[1].formatted_address;  //This returns from this callback
    }
 }
}
```

This can be demonstrated by the (generally evil) `setTimeout` to fake the async request:

```
function callMe(value) {
    setTimeout(function() { return value; }, 3000);

  return "This is not the value";
}

var result = callMe("This is the value");

console.log(result);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cok3h4tn/1/

You can see "This is not the value" is being printed because `return "This is not the value";` is the return, and not `return value;`.

Here's the [google maps sample for geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple), you can see how it uses the result in the callback, rather than trying to return it.

Or, here's another example of how to work with the callback:
Take this example code as the starting point.
It doesn't work, but it's a starting point.

```
function callMe(value) {
    setTimeout(function() { return value; }, 3000);

    return "This is not the value";
}

var result = callMe("This is the value");

console.log(result);
```

`callMe` is called, then we want to take the result, and do something with it.
We could write this another way, where the "something" we want to do with the result is in it's own function `handleResult`.

```
function handleResult(result) {
    console.log(result);
}

function callMe(value) {
    setTimeout(function() { return value; }, 3000);

    return "This is not the value";
}

var result = callMe("This is the value");

handleResult(result);
```

Now that's still incorrect because the "wrong" result is still being passed to `handleResult`.
So, we need to make a change that will pass the "right" result to `handleResult`.

```
function handleResult(result) {
    console.log(result);
}

function callMe(value) {
    setTimeout(function() { handleResult(value); }, 3000);

    return "This is not the value";
}

callMe("This is the value");
```

Updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cok3h4tn/4/

Comment: Then how am I supposed to access in that case?

Comment: The callback is called when the data is available. The google sample shows the data being used. I've also added an extra example showing the approach in a generic way. There's plenty of examples around of how to use callbacks in javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442321/callback-function-example