# Coud you help me understand the code ? the task is to find first non consecutive number

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, find, simplification

```
const firstNonConsecutive = arr => arr.find((number, index) => index > 1 && number !== arr[index -1] + 1)
```

Is there anyone who could help me break the above function down for me ?
I wrote a very long code to solve the task and someone sent me a correction and said my code could be simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do to decompose this would be to add curly braces and break it down in multiple lines:

```js
// This function takes an Array
const firstNonConsecutive = arr => {
  // And tries to find an item
  return arr.find((number, index) => {
    return index > 1 && // Starting from index 2 (the first 2 are ignored)
      number !== arr[index - 1] + 1; // Where the value is not (previous value + 1)
  });
}

console.log(firstNonConsecutive([128, 6, 2, 8])); // 2         -> ??
console.log(firstNonConsecutive([5, 6, 2, 8]));   // 2         -> correct
console.log(firstNonConsecutive([5, 6, 7, 8]));   // undefined -> correct
```

Then, if you don't know that method, you could look up some documentation on [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). It takes a [callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442321/callback-function-example) which it will execute on every item until that callback returns `true` *(or any [truthy value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642809/understanding-javascript-truthy-and-falsy))* at some point. If it does, it will return that value. Otherwise, if no item matches the condition, it will return `undefined`.

This should be enough to understand what it does?

The weird thing is that is starts from index 2 (`index > 1)`. Using this logic, this means the very first item is never checked. Maybe that condition should be `index > 0`:

```js
// This function takes an Array
const firstNonConsecutive = arr => {
  // And tries to find an item
  return arr.find((number, index) => {
    return index > 0 && // Starting from index 1 (the first is ignored)
      number !== arr[index - 1] + 1; // Where the value is not (previous value + 1)
  });
}

console.log(firstNonConsecutive([128, 6, 2, 8])); // 6         -> correct
console.log(firstNonConsecutive([5, 6, 2, 8]));   // 2         -> correct
console.log(firstNonConsecutive([5, 6, 7, 8]));   // undefined -> correct
```

Here is a more deconstructed way to write this:

```js
function firstNonConsecutive(arr) {
  // Find an item that passes the condition
  return arr.find(passesCondition);
  
  function passesCondition(number, index) {
    return index > 0 && number !== arr[index - 1] + 1;
  }
}

console.log(firstNonConsecutive([128, 6, 2, 8])); // 6         -> correct
console.log(firstNonConsecutive([5, 6, 2, 8]));   // 2         -> correct
console.log(firstNonConsecutive([5, 6, 7, 8]));   // undefined -> correct
```

Comment: I think I understand that but I have a few questions
1. We are creating a function called "firstNonConsecutive" and the parameter is any array
2. the function uses the find.array function and … what does that "(number, index)" do ? Does it loop through an array ? Are these properties inside the curly brackets parameters ?

Comment: 1. Correct. 2. The only parameter we pass to `.find()` is a function (commonly called _callback_). That function will be executed for every item in the Array (until it finds something). And every time, this callback will be called with 2 parameters: `number`, which is the value of the current item, and `index`, which is the position of the current item in the Array.

Comment: Inside the curly brackets is the _body_ of the function, which will be executed every time, for every item. Note: this syntax `(x) => {...}` is _([almost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable))_ equivalent to `function(x) { ... }`

Comment: I added a third example in my answer above