# How does a function execute when a local function is added onto it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I call the following function

```js
console.log("Hello World!");
```

I expect it to print `Hello World!` and thats all fine and dandy, but what happens when I add a local function, like

```js
console.log(target, function(err, reply) {
        console.log("Hello World!")
    });
```

It seems I can add on this local function to anything

```js
foo(function(err, reply) {
}
```

I am curious

1. How the local function operates inside of the other function
2. Is there a certain way the local function should be handled
3. Cases where this should be or shouldn't be used.

Comment: Please point me to any other question that may answer my confusion, I was unsure as how to phrase the question or relevant terminology so couldn't find anything that answered this for me

Comment: A function that is passed to another function as an argument is typically called a "callback".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Callback function example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442321/callback-function-example)

Comment: `console.log()` doesn't call callbacks. So there's nothing special going on there, it's just printing the function itself.

Comment: You seem to be asking for general rules of some kind, but broadly across all code that could ever possibly be written in JavaScript.  Narrow your scope.  Specifically with regards to the code shown, what's not clear to me is (1) why you're passing a function to `console.log` in the first place, (2) what you're expecting the result of that operation to be, or (3) how the observed result of that operation differs from what you expect.  With regards to the `foo` function, we don't know what that function does (if anything) with what's passed to it.

Comment: Stack Overflow works much better if you have a problem, it's not really a "How does this work sort of site".

Answer (score 0):

Functions, in JavaScript, are first class objects. Anything you can do with an object, you can do with a function, including passing it as an argument.

> How the local function operates inside of the other function

The same way it "operates" anywhere else for whatever value of "operate" you care to define. e.g. If you pass it to `console.log` then it will get logged, it won't be called because the internal logic of `console.log` doesn't call functions that are passed as arguments to it. (Unlike, for example [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).)

> Is there a certain way the local function should be handled

Not in the general case.

> Cases where this should be or shouldn't be used.

That's too broad and too much of a matter of opinion to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` can accept any number of parameters and will just output all of them to the console.

```js
console.log("hello world!", 69420, true, false, function () {console.log("hello world!");})
```

Passing a function to `console.log` will just output the function itself into the console.
Also, in the snippet you showed, `target` is undefined and running it will throw an error.